# Complex SQL query for getting the status of orders

Tags: mysql, sql

### The Tables

So, I have a `line_items` table that links up with an `orders` table. Obviously a single `order` can have multiple `line_item`s.

A `line_item` has (among other things) an `item_status`. All of the `item_status`es are listed in a table called, naturally, `item_statuses`. There is a `stage` column in that table which indicates the linear nature of the status. So, an `item_status` of `proofing` has a `stage` of `20`, because it comes earlier in the production pipeline than, say, `printing`, which is `60`. `shipping` is `80`, etc. You get the idea. It indicates the `line_item`’s status in the production pipeline.

So, it’s easy enough for me to see how many `line_item`s a given `order` has and group them by their `item_status`. An `order` might have 2 `line_item`s that are in the `shipping` department, but 1 item that is still `printing`. Make sense so far?

### The View

As a step to my ultimate goal, I will need to determine an `order`’s "status". To do this, I’ve decided that an `order`’s "status" will be the same as *earliest* `item_status` of all of its `line_item`s. (I use quotes for the `order`'s "status" because it’s never really stored anywhere, just calculated on the fly. A View will help to kinda store it.)

So, if an `order` has 3 `line_item`s, with `item_status`es of `printing`, `shipping`, and `shipping`, then the overall `order`’s “status” should be `printing`, because it has a `line_item` that is still stuck in that earlier `item_status`. (Since `printing` has a lower `stage` number in the `item_statuses` table than `shipping`.)

I’d like to create a View that will give me the `order` number and its “status” for *all* records in the `orders` table.

### The Goal

*Ultimately*, I will need to get a count of all `order`s by their `ship_date` (which is also a column in the `orders` table), but broken down by their "status". (So, for example, a given `ship_date` will have 78 `order`s that are `shipping`, 139 `printing`, and 43 `proofing`. I think creating the View I mentioned would be a stepping stone toward this goal.)

### The Progress

So far, this is all I've been able to come up with:

```
SELECT
  orders.ship_date_id,
  orders.id,
  item_statuses.id
FROM item_statuses
  JOIN line_items
    ON item_statuses.id = line_items.item_status_id
  JOIN orders
    ON line_items.order_id = orders.id
WHERE item_statuses.stage = (
  SELECT MIN(item_statuses.stage)
  FROM item_statuses
    JOIN (
           SELECT line_items.item_status_id
           FROM line_items
             JOIN orders
               ON line_items.order_id = orders.id
           WHERE orders.id = '521079'
         ) AS x
      ON x.item_status_id = item_statuses.id
)
```

It's ugly. It's complex. And all it does is get the "earliest" `item_status` for a single, hard-coded `order`, then shows only the orders with that "status". I need this to be able to show me *all* orders and their associated "status"es.

### The Question

And all of this is only to get me part of the way to my goal. As I mentioned earlier, I will eventually need this to get a count of all orders, separated by date (within a week range) and see how many orders are in each "status" for that day.

The worst part is that I *know* that this should be possible; there's probably even an elegant solution to it that I just cannot see. Thus, I have come here as a last resort.

Comment: Adding sample data and expected output would help visualizing the problem.

Comment: This looks like a good question. I'd add as an aside that questions are best without i-really-have-tried and help-me-i-am-begging-you boilerplate; the paradox of insisting at length that one has made a solid effort is that the question might get a poor reception for its wordiness. [I've outlined this here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions). Thus, keep questions as succinct as you can - it will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (somewhat) simpler than you think it is.  Let's build this up.

First, let's get the stage for all items:

```
SELECT Line_Items.order_id, Item_Statuses.stage
FROM Line_Items
JOIN Item_Statuses
  ON Item_Statuses.id = Line_Items.item_status_id
```

This gives something (probably) looking like this:

```
1 | 20
1 | 39
2 | 50
```

Okay, now, since there's multiple lines for each order, we need the minimum stage for each order.  Simple aggregate:

```
SELECT Line_Items.order_id, MIN(Item_Status.stage) AS stage
FROM Line_Items
JOIN Item_Statuses
  ON Item_Statuses.id = Line_Items.item_status_id
GROUP BY Line_Items.order_id
```

Which would yield:

```
1 | 20
2 | 50
```

Now, since you want the shipping date, we need to join the `Orders` table to the entire result set of the previous query.  That means we need a subquery:

```
SELECT Orders.id, Orders.ship_date_id,
       Order_Status.stage,
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Line_Items.order_id, MIN(Item_Status.stage) AS stage
           FROM Line_Items
           JOIN Item_Statuses
             ON Item_Statuses.id = Line_Items.item_status_id
           GROUP BY Line_Items.order_id) AS Order_Status
       ON Order_Status.order_id = Orders.id
```

Which would yield:

```
1 | "2015-01-01" | 20
2 | "2015-01-04" | 50
3 | "2015-01-05" | (null) -- you might have orders without line items!
```

It's unclear if you want/there are text descriptions of the stages.  If so, you'll also need to join to the status table again:

```
SELECT Orders.id, Orders.ship_date_id,
       Item_Statuses.stage,
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Line_Items.order_id, MIN(Item_Status.stage) AS stage
           FROM Line_Items
           JOIN Item_Statuses
             ON Item_Statuses.id = Line_Items.item_status_id
           GROUP BY Line_Items.order_id) AS Order_Status
       ON Order_Status.order_id = Orders.id
JOIN Item_Statuses
  ON Item_Status.stage = Order_Status.stage
```

(This particular version assumes that `stage` is a unique value - if it's not, you have other problems, though)

```
1 | "2015-01-01" | 'Printing'
2 | "2015-01-04" | 'Proofing'
3 | "2015-01-05" | (null) -- you might have orders without line items!
```

---

What about getting the count of orders?

Well, getting the count of orders for a specific date is easy:

```
SELECT Orders.ship_date_id, COUNT(*) as orders
FROM Orders
GROUP By Orders.ship_date_id

"2015-01-01" | 1
"2015-01-04" | 400
"2015-04-05" | 33
```

You can then mostly merge the two queries together:

```
SELECT Orders.ship_date_id, Order_Status.stage,
       COUNT(*) AS orders
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Line_Items.order_id, MIN(Item_Status.stage) AS stage
           FROM Line_Items
           JOIN Item_Statuses
             ON Item_Statuses.id = Line_Items.item_status_id
           GROUP BY Line_Items.order_id) AS Order_Status
       ON Order_Status.order_id = Orders.id
GROUP BY Orders.ship_date_id, Order_Status.stage
```

So something like:

```
"2015-01-01" | 20     | 1 
"2015-01-04" | 30     | 200
"2015-01-04" | 40     | 200
"2015-04-05" | 40     | 2
"2015-04-05" | 20     | 30
"2015-04-05" | (null) | 1
```

(If at this point you want stage names, it's best to push the entire query into a subquery and join again for the name, because otherwise you have to add the name as an extra column in the grouping.  This is left as an exercise for the reader.)

If you want to restrict your date range, you can include it in the view, but I'd probably leave it off and just add the `WHERE` clause when you query the view itself:

```
SELECT ship_date_id, stage, orders
FROM Orders_Per_Day
WHERE ship_date_id >= :start
      AND ship_date_id < :end
```

Astute readers will notice there are gaps in the date range.  Joining to a calendar table (the recommended way to get missing dates) - whether in the view or not - is also left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a more complete and easy-to-follow step-by-step answer to my question. Thank you so much, @Clockwork-Muse!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not as complex as long is your post. :)

I think what you seek is this:

```
SELECT 
  tbl.ship_date_id,
  tbl.order_id,
  tbl.item_status_id order_status
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    orders.ship_date_id,
    orders.id order_id,
    item_statuses.id item_status_id,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY orders.id ORDER BY item_statuses.id ASC) rn
  FROM orders 
  JOIN line_items     ON line_items.order_id = orders.id
  JOIN item_statuses  ON item_statuses.id = line_items.item_status_id
) tbl
WHERE tbl.rn = 1
```

Then you should be able to do your statistics based on ship_date_id`s

This should work under the assumption that `item_statuses.id` is a number that increments as your process progresses (i.e. `printing` has id 3 and `shipping` has id 4`, etc.)

***Explanation:***
the ROW_NUMBER function will order the items on each order (1,2,3,...) based on the `item_statuses.id` and we just need to take one row for the item at the earliest step in the process.